# Safari browser and CSS border-radius displaying straight line on right side

Tags: css, button, safari

[image: demo]

As you can see in the above screenshot, Safari Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17) on a Macbook Air displays the border-radius on the right side with a straight line.  The "button" is a link tag with a class applied to it.  This same button displays properly in Chrome but not Safari. It's driving me crazy as to why this is happening.

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/unnmv/

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```css
background: $color;
border: 1px solid darken($color, 15%);
color: $text-color;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
outline: none;
padding: 0.5em 2em;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
height: auto;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
```

Comment: You sure it's not getting clipped by its containing element?

Comment: Please post your HTML and if possible a jsFiddle.

Comment: please share JS fiddle link

Comment: is there a `background-color` set on parent element?

Comment: Added the JSFiddle link in the original post. When I viewed it in Chrome it looked fine, then I viewed it in Safari and it has the line on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:  Add the following to your css:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
```

I noticed it is mentioned for spacing consistency issues between browser, so I tried it out with this issue since i was having the same.  It worked for me.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the CSS but it didn't fix the problem.  I'm not really sure what the solution is to this strange issue; I guess I'll have to do some serious debugging and change 1 thing at a time till I find what causes the problem.  I'll update this question with a solution if I find one that works.